# Streaming file from Golang backend to Node frontend

Tags: node.js, file, express, go, streaming

I have set up a backend on **Golang** (wrapped in Gin gonic framework) and the frontend is run on **NodeJS** (wrapped in Express framework). Assume Express is to make a request to Golang backend to request a file, receive it back to Express and push to the client.

**Frontend Node:**

```
var request = require('request');

router.get('/testfile', function (req, res, next) {

  // URL to Golang backend server
  var filepath = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/testfile';

  request(filepath, function (error, response, body) {

    // This is incorrect, as it's just rendering the body to the client as text
    res.send(body);  

  })

});
```

**Backend Golang:**

```
r.GET("/testfile", func(c *gin.Context) {

    url := "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Wiki.png"

    timeout := time.Duration(5) * time.Second
    transport := &http.Transport{
        ResponseHeaderTimeout: timeout,
        Dial: func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            return net.DialTimeout(network, addr, timeout)
        },
        DisableKeepAlives: true,
    }
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: transport,
    }
    resp, err := client.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Wiki.png")
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", c.Request.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
    c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Length", c.Request.Header.Get("Content-Length"))

    //stream the body to the client without fully loading it into memory
    io.Copy(c.Writer, resp.Body)

})
```

My question is: **How do I properly request a file from Node to Golang, and render it back to the client, keeping the possibility of streaming file (if there would be a large file)?**

Comment: If you just need a file [http.FileServer()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) will do most of work for ya. From node request it as any other file.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the `request` library specifically, but essentially you need something like the following (judging from the `request` documentation):

```
const request = require('request')

// ...

router.get('/my-route', async (req, res) => {
  const requestResponse = await request('...')
  const binaryFile = Buffer.from(requestResponse.body, 'binary')

  res.type(requestResponse.headers('content-type'))
  res.end(binaryFile)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

readable.pip(writeable)

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require("http")

const app = express()

app.get("/path", (req, res, next) => {
    http.get("http://golang/server/url", (res2) => {
        res2.pipe(res)
    })
})
```